# How can I use Excel to scrape data from a website

Tags: html, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to use Excel to scrape market data from a website, but the website's format is not conducive to simple scraping. My code runs until the second Set statement within the For loop and then throws the run-time error. What am I missing? Code below for reference:

```
Sub Get_CME_Data()
 
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant
Dim tbody As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim td As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim trObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
 
 
'Website to go to.
website = "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_settlements_futures.html"
 
'Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 
'Where to go and how to go there
request.Open "GET", website, False
 
'Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
 
'Send the request for the webpage
request.send
 
'Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
 
'Put the webpage into an html object to make data reference easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response
 
'Get the price from the specified element on the page.
Set tbody = html.getElementsByTagName("tbody").Item(0)
Set tr = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")
For i = 0 To 2
    Set trObj = tr.Item(i)
    Set td = trObj.getElementsByTagName("td")
    Set price = td.Item(1).innerText
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i + 1) = price
Next
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you want is dynamically retrieved from a different xhr, hence why it won't be found in your initial request as shown.

The actual request for the data is:

`https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/425/FUT?tradeDate=12/03/2020&strategy=DEFAULT&pageSize=50&_=1607023376571`

It is a query string format with a timestamp on the end which can likely be removed except in cases of frequent requests; then any random number would probably serve, or indeed the current header you have to mitigate against cached results be served.

The above endpoint returns json which you would need a json parser, like jsonconverter.bas, to handle.

You can find this in the network tab when refreshing the page. Check whether web-scraping is allowed and you may be able to use this endpoint. It is more likely a better idea to find a dedicated (free) API which serves you the desired price data.

Perhaps the following *"real-time API solution for every CME Group product and instrument"* - though may involve a cost.

`https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/market-tech-and-data-services/cme-reference-data-api.html`

I think free but price only (only skim read):

`https://www.quandl.com/databases/MWCS/documentation`